# Adding Swing components to Eclipse RCP plugin

Tags: java, swing, eclipse-plugin, swt

I'm having trouble embedding Swing components inside SWT (such as eclipse plugin..)
Currently what I have:

```
 public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
  java.awt.Frame f = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(parent);
  JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  JButton button = new JButton("Swing button");
  JLabel label = new JLabel("Swing label");
  panel.add(label,BorderLayout.NORTH);
  panel.add(button,BorderLayout.CENTER);
  f.add(panel);
 }
```

This code snippet fails to load, the plugin crashes on the first line...

Any idea how to incorporate these components?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html

Minimally, embedding an AWT frame inside an SWT composite is just two simple lines of code

```
Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your code is failing at the first line then please first make sure that the parent `Composite` is created using `SWT.EMBEDDED`. If it is not then create a child composite using the `SWT.EMBEDDED` and then call

```
java.awt.Frame f = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(newChildComposite);
```

> An instance of
>   org.eclipse.swt.Composite is created
>   with the SWT.EMBEDDED style. This
>   style signals that an AWT frame is to
>   be embedded inside the Composite. The
>   call to the static new_Frame method
>   creates and returns such a frame. The
>   frame may then be populated with AWT
>   and/or Swing components.

Taken from [Article-Swing-SWT-Integration](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html)